# Принципы подбора значений для плавной анимации, описанной в xml для android

Tags: android-sdk, android, анимация

**Дано:**

8 анимаций типа `translate` пошагово перемещающих цель по диагонали и обратно. См. gif №1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-40"
    android:fromYDelta="-40"
    android:toXDelta="-20"
    android:toYDelta="-10"/>

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-20"
    android:fromYDelta="-10"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toXDelta="-10"
    android:toYDelta="0"/>

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-10"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:startOffset="600"
    android:toXDelta="20"
    android:toYDelta="10"/>

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="20"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:startOffset="900"
    android:toXDelta="40"
    android:toYDelta="40"/>

<!---->

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="40"
    android:fromYDelta="40"
    android:startOffset="1200"
    android:toXDelta="20"
    android:toYDelta="10"/>

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="20"
    android:fromYDelta="10"
    android:startOffset="1500"
    android:toXDelta="-10"
    android:toYDelta="0"/>


<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-10"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:startOffset="1800"
    android:toXDelta="-20"
    android:toYDelta="-10"/>

<translate
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXDelta="-20"
    android:fromYDelta="-10"
    android:startOffset="2100"
    android:toXDelta="-40"
    android:toYDelta="-40"/>
</set>
```

**Задача:**

Сделать анимацию плавной. Вот как в "play пресса" приложении от гугла. См. gif №2.

**Возможное решение:**

Поиграться с длительностью анимации. Возможно, выкрутив её, на максимум будет выглядеть плавно.

**Вопрос:**

Какие параметры анимации надо учитывать для создания плавного движения?

**Что у меня получилось, gif №1:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Чего бы хотелось, gif №2:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в gif2 не translate, а scale.

Comment: Вполне возможно. Но мне бы хотелось сделать плавной именно translate. Я повысил длительность и выглядит вполне нормально, вроде. Но думается мне, это не единственный подход к решению проблемы.

Comment: Если создавать анимацию программно, то можно использовать `Interpolator`. `AccelerateDeccelerateInterpolator`, который плавно ускоряет вначале и замедляет вконце анимацию. Не знаю, можно ли указать `Interpolator` через xml

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. В xml указать можно - я вот это нагуглил `android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"`. Улучшения от его применения заметны, но без увеличения, дополнительно, длительности не дают полной плавности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовав советы @metalurgus и свои эксперименты, пришёл к следующему выводу:

1. Длительность анимации прямо пропорциональна плавности.
2. Использование `Interpolator` также способствует её увеличению.
3. Совмещение `translate` и `scale` анимаций также помогает.
4. Также полезно запускать следующую анимацию до конца предыдущей.

Итого анимацию я сделал так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="4500"
        android:fromXScale="0.9"
        android:fromYScale="0.9"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.1"
        android:toYScale="1.1"/>
    <scale
        android:duration="4500"
        android:fromXScale="1.1"
        android:fromYScale="1.1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="4500"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="-40"
        android:fromYDelta="-40"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:toXDelta="-20"
        android:toYDelta="-10"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="-20"
        android:fromYDelta="-10"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="1000"
        android:toXDelta="-10"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="-10"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:toXDelta="20"
        android:toYDelta="10"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"

        android:fromXDelta="20"
        android:fromYDelta="10"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="3000"
        android:toXDelta="40"
        android:toYDelta="40"/>

    <!---->

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="40"
        android:fromYDelta="40"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="4000"
        android:toXDelta="20"
        android:toYDelta="10"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="20"
        android:fromYDelta="10"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="5000"
        android:toXDelta="-10"
        android:toYDelta="0"/>


    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="-10"
        android:fromYDelta="0"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="6000"
        android:toXDelta="-20"
        android:toYDelta="-10"/>

    <translate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXDelta="-20"
        android:fromYDelta="-10"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
        android:startOffset="7000"
        android:toXDelta="-40"
        android:toYDelta="-40"/>
</set>
```

И вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]